# Can I pick healthy unripe green tomatoes from a plant that has blossom end rot?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes, blossom-end-rot

All my tomato plants have blossom rot.  As the fruit begins to ripen, they are rotted at the bottom.  Can I pick the healthy green tomatoes and let them ripen without them getting the rotted bottom?

Answer (score 3):

This question and its answer [Are blossom end rot tomatoes edible?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/34560/are-blossom-end-rot-tomatoes-edible/34561#34561) is relevant to your question. If you correct your watering regime, the remaining, unaffected tomatoes on the plants should be fine. Occasionally, there is an actual shortage of calcium in the soil,so if this happens every year, even though you water correctly, get a soil test done to check the calcium levels.

You could  remove the green tomatoes, but they won't be as sweet as the ones that ripen naturally on the plant, and depending how advanced they are, may not ripen at all - a sunny windowsill should help with ripening.

Comment: I always allow tomatoes to ripen out of the sun.  Once they show that they are in a ripening stage such as a bit of yellowing they do fine in the shade and cool.  Ripening slowly.  And heck, I haven't found that changes the flavor at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that.  Placing your tomatoes near some bananas and/or apples can help them ripen faster because they release a lot of etylene gas, which prompts other fruit to ripen.

An alternative would be making some pickled green tomatoes!  I love pickled green tomatoes.  Sweet, tangy and a nice refreshing crunch on sandwiches the rest of the year!

Answer (score 2):

Once they start to "blush" or turn color from solid green to orange/red they should redden fully with time. So yes, you can, and you can also eat them green (much like eating green bell peppers instead of letting them turn red/yellow/orange).

As others have said, it's probably not too late to try and remedy your blossom end rot issue and may be worth a try. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can cut the good healthy parts off the tomato and use that section. We grow tons of tomatoes and we cut out the bad spots.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a tomato get blossom end rot *after* being harvested whether or not it's left to ripen indoors, and I've had a fair number of harvested, unripe tomatoes ripen indoors. I'm not about to say it's impossible (although maybe it is), but I've definitely never seen it happen.

It may be past the time of year where blossom end rot is much of a problem, though, depending on where you live. In my area, it's mostly much of a problem during the hottest parts of the season, and we've recently went beyond those.

Answer (score 2):

Any green tomato picked unripe will eventually ripen indoors given the right conditions- some like to hasten the process with  other over ripe fruit placed nearby- just inspect them every day although generally the smaller the fruit the more difficult to ripen - think smaller than a marble- and it becomes a pointless task, anything above that and depending on how early you pick will add extra time on how long it will take. you always get a few every year like this.