# Green Pepper Plant with Blossom End Rot

Tags: peppers, rot, edible

The peppers on my green pepper plant have Blossom End Rot.  Can I cut off the bad part and eat the unblemished part?  I have one plant growing in a planter.  It is in direct sun most of the day.  With as hot as it has been here in Delaware I have been watering it 2 times each day.  (Otherwise the plant droops.)

Comment: Hi Karen, can you add a photo?

Comment: Here's a related question about tomatoes: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/34560/are-blossom-end-rot-tomatoes-edible

Answer (score 1):

Blossom end rot is a physiological condition (due to calcium / water uptake issues), so technically the good part of the pepper is still safe to eat.  But the longer the pepper has blossom end rot, the higher the chance of developing secondary disease and/or pest issues.  I would recommend using your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

With or without seeing the outside of it, would suggest might have to look at the inside of it too, and also if the fruit is situated such that gravity would tend to pull nastiness away from the rest of the fruit; Consuming something nasty would be a very poor idea and could be very unhealthful! and likely have a nasty flavour! If the interior is extensively nasty, would scrap the whole fruit! But if only a small amount of disrepair at the tip of the fruit is present, then after thorough rinsing After trimming, maybe would be ok: might be sort of like trimming off a blemish. So it really depends on the extent, & whether the rest of the fruit is firm & nice! Maybe try adding some something to the soil to help reduce the occurrence, as there might be mild mineral deficiencies, such as calcium etc.