# Blossom end rot contamination

Tags: tomatoes, blossom-end-rot

I boiled down tomatoes for sauce and discovered that a couple had blossom end rot inside. I pulled out any black I could find. Is this pot of sauce now inedible?

Comment: Hi Amy, welcome to the site!  Does this answer your question? [Are blossom end rot tomatoes edible?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/34560/are-blossom-end-rot-tomatoes-edible)

Comment: Hi, it does not answer my question. That answer deals with the tomato flesh after the black rot is cut out. I had black rot found in a pot of boiled tomatoes. So, good tomatoes were boiled along WITH black rot. I have thrown out the entire pot of tomato sauce as I couldn't find anything on whether black rot is poisonous. I didn't want to chance it.

Comment: Better safe than sorry.  Sorry we couldn't be more help.